# How many ways to reach a given tennis-score?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say a tennis player wins a set with a game score of 6-3. In how many different ways can we reach this score?

Assuming H means the home-player won the game and A means the away-player won the game, one permutation would be HHHHHAAAH.

Note that the winner of the set will always have to win the last game (so maybe I could reduce this to how many permutations are there of the set of HHHHH AAA?)

I realize I have almost solved the problem but I'm still having problems grasping it, any ideas or if you could point me in the correct directions would be helpful.

For those unfamiliar with [the tennis scoring system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system), a set is a sequence of games.  The set score is simply a count of how many games each player won.  For purposes of this question, all you need to know is that the first person to win a total of 6 games wins the set.

Comment: If I remember correctly, scorekeeping in tennis is completely bizarre, with different amounts of points earned in different stages of the game. Are you sure "6-3" actually means that one player has won 6 round/games/whatever and the other has won 3?

Comment: I am actually talking about Set-scores where a player wins if he gets 6 games (he needs 7 if the other player also have 5).

My problem is just as stated above, how many unique ways are there to order the set of letters "HHHHHHAAA" ?

Comment: @Henning: You’re thinking of the scoring within a game; $6$-$3$ is a possible score of a completed set, which one player has won six games to three.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system Tennis scoring isn't *that* bad, once you realize there are actually three layers of scoring in a match and that the names for scores are completely silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you saw yourself, you’re looking for the number of permutions of five H’s and three A’s. That’s a string of $8$ symbols, and the A’s can occupy any $3$ of the $8$ positions, so the desired number is simply the number of ways to choose $3$ things from a set of $8$ things. This is the binomial coefficient

$$\binom83=\frac{8!}{3!5!}=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{6}=56\;.$$

Comment: Choose your answer as correct over the others because you also gave me the term Binomial Coefficient. Thanks to the rest of you as well (Cant upvote, dont have enough reputation)

Comment: @taracus: You do now. :-) Feel free to upvote any of the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Wow I do, and I did, just bragged to my co-worker that I had enough reputation on math.stackexchange to start upvoting, he looked puzzled.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost home! You've correctly reduced the problem to "how many ways can we introduce three As into a five Hs". So, of the eight positions which we can label $1$, $2$, $\dots$, $8$, three positions must be As, so a score stream such as HHAAHHAH might be represented as $\{3,4,7\}$.

Hence, we can look at it as "how many $3$-element subsets are there of an $8$-element set".

Answer (score 1):

Those are called Permutations with repetition in general, repetitions are taken care of by dividing the permutation by the factorial of  the number of objects that are identical.So you have $5$ letters $H$ and $3$ letters $A$ hence the number of permutations is $$\frac{8!}{3!\cdot 5!}=56$$